# Enable or disable a input fields with checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a form that will be enabled and disabled depending on the checkbox tick mark.

```html
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>Is this client user</p>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="is_user"
          id="is_user"
          onclick="enableCreateUser()"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="user_register">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label class="" for="username">Username:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label class="" for="password">Password:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to make this javascript or jquery function that will allow me to disable or enable this portion with `id="user_register"`.

Here is the code that I tried.

```js
    function enableCreateUser() {
        if (document.getElementById("is_user").checked) {
            document.getElementById("user_register").disabled = true;
        }

        if (!document.getElementById("is_user").checked) {
            document.getElementById("user_register").disabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Please help me complete this function. Thank you.

Comment: You want to disable `input` only or the whole section ?

Comment: flase is a typo and should be false. Also use else instead of checking both

Comment: You can not “disable” a `div` element. You will need to loop over the input elements inside this and disable them each individually - or you need to group them using a `fieldset`, _that_ can be disabled. And don’t use onclick on checkbox elements, use onchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) with [add](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add) and [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove) function to add custom class `.disable_section` to show disabled on your section.

**Live Demo:**

```js
function enableCreateUser() {
  if (document.getElementById("is_user").checked) {
    document.getElementById("user_register").classList.add('disable_section')
  } else {
    document.getElementById("user_register").classList.remove('disable_section')
  }
}
```

```css
.disable_section {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <p>Is this client user</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="is_user" id="is_user" onclick="enableCreateUser()" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="user_register">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="" for="username">Username:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="" for="password">Password:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to disable the `inputs` **specifically** then you can simply assign `ids` to your inputs and disable them individually.

**Live Demo**

```js
function enableCreateUser() {
  if (document.getElementById("is_user").checked) {
    document.getElementById("user_res").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("pass").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("user_res").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("pass").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <p>Is this client user</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="is_user" id="is_user" onclick="enableCreateUser()" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="user_register">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="" for="username">Username:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="user_res" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="" for="password">Password:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="pass" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is another way to solve this question. Upvoted. @Alwayshelping.

Comment: This is great code, but has an issue.  And that is if there are other required fields on the same form, and the form is posted and one of the other fields has an error, the shaded fields are no longer shaded.  Might be better to actually REMOVE the fields if the box is checked?  However, they might come back on a post as well, not sure.

Comment: I figured out how to fix the problem I mentioned in the comment above.  Simply add this on the page in the script code:
`
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
  enableCreateUser();
});
</script>
`

Answer (score 1):

```js
function enableCreateUser() {
  if (document.getElementById("is_user").checked) {
    disableForm(true);
  }
  if (!document.getElementById("is_user").checked) {
    disableForm(false);
  }

}

function disableForm(flag) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control");
  for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; ++i) {
    elements[i].readOnly = flag;
    elements[i].disabled = flag;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <p>Is this client user</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="is_user" id="is_user" onclick="enableCreateUser()" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="user_register">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="" for="username">Username:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="" for="password">Password:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

**NOTE :** Remove onclick on checkbox.

`<input type="checkbox" name="is_user" id="is_user" />`

```js
$('#is_user').on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('#user_register input').prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $('#user_register input').prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use [.hidden()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden) for control div

```js
function enableCreateUser() {
    var status = document.getElementById("is_user").checked;
    document.getElementById("user_register").hidden = status;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>Is this client user</p>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="is_user"
          id="is_user"
          onclick="enableCreateUser()"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="user_register">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label class="" for="username">Username:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label class="" for="password">Password:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>PURFECT MATCH</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function enableCreateUser() {
            var form_elements = document.getElementById("myForm").elements;
            if (document.getElementById("is_user").checked){
                for (var i = 0; i < form_elements.length; ++i) 
                    form_elements[i].readOnly = true;
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < form_elements.length; ++i) 
                    form_elements[i].readOnly = false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="enableCreateUser();">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>Is this client user</p>
            <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="is_user"
            id="is_user"
            onclick="enableCreateUser()"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="user_register">
        <form id="myForm" >
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label class="" for="username">Username:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label class="" for="password">Password:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have added form having id `myForm`. In the JavaScript section, using this id function `enableCreateUser()` access the form and we iterates over the elements of the form, setting their read-only status based on the value of checkbox `is_user`.

To initialize form elements we calling function `enableCreateUser()` just after the loading of document is done using `onload` in `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this might be an old question, but you can also use an event listener for the checkbox, and simply toggle the attribute disabled on and off for the desired input. Like this:

```
yourCheckbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
  yourInput.toggleAttribute('disabled');
});
```

Using the code you posted, it might look like this:

```
const yourCheckbox = document.querySelector('#is_user');

yourCheckbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const yourInput = document.querySelector('#user_register');

  yourInput.toggleAttribute('disabled');
});
```